# How to bind the SharePoint 2013 list data to a dropdown list in a gridview of asp.net using csom

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have an employee list in Sharepoint that has 2 lookup fields(manager and department).

I want to know how to bind the lookup field values to the asp.net DropDownList.

So I get a dropdown with SharePoint list data bound to the gridview.

I already can see a post relevant to this but that is using SP 2010. I am in need of code for  SP 2013

Thanks! Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If I need for DropDownList to fetch data from SP list, I use something like this

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(http://sharepointSiteWithList))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["listName"];
            dd.DataSource = list.Items;
            dd.DataValueField = "Department";
            dd.DataTextField = "Department";
            dd.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be done with 2013 version.

**.Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpbind" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Add Namespace:**

```
Using microsoft.SharePoint;
```

**.Cs Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  

if (!Page.IsPostBack)   
{  
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursharepointsite"))   
    {  
        using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())   
        {  
            SPList list = web.Lists["Authors"];  
            drpbind.DataSource = list.Items;  
            drpbind.DataValueField = "Title";   
            drpbind.DataTextField = "Title";   
            drpbind.DataBind();  
        }  
    }  
}  

}
```

Ref: [More detailed steps](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/bind-dropdownlist-in-sharepoint-using-C-Sharp/).

Ref: [To bind GridView](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/bind-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-gridview/).